# Contraction of distances in explanation of relativity of simultaneity in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I was going through my old college notes on special relativity and found a reasoning that a professor used to explain why the simultaneity of events is relative. But I believe there is a mistake in the explanation, and I would like to know if I am right or not and why.

The reasoning is the following. We have two people, denoted by 1 and 2. Person 2 gets in a train while person 1 waits and looks from outside at what is happening inside the train, that moves in a straight line at a constant speed v.

At a given moment, person 2 gets positioned in the middle of the train, at the same distance (that we will call $d$) from the front as from the back, points a torch towards the front, another towards the back and turns them on at the same time.

From the point of view of person 2, the light reaches the front and the back of the train at the same time, where this time is:

$$t=\dfrac{d}{c}$$

However, from the point of view of person 1, who is looking from outside, the time that the light takes to reach the front of the train is given by:

$$t_1=\dfrac{d+vt_1}{c}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  t_1=\dfrac{d}{c-v}$$

while the time that the light takes to reach the back is:

$$t_2=\dfrac{d-vt_2}{c}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ t_2=\dfrac{d}{c+v}$$

This means that $t_1>t_2$, and so both events are not simultaneous from the point of view of person 1.

**My question:** we know that distances are contracted in special relativity. At this point of the lecture, which was the first time that special relativity was discussed, it's normal that the teacher didn't mention this fact. However, doesn't this affect the reasoning? From the point of view of person 1, the distance $d$ should be replaced by $d'=\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}\cdot d$, and the distances $vt_1$ and $vt_2$ remain unaltered (not contracted). Right? And the conclusion ($t_1>t_2$ for person 1) remains the same?

Comment: You are correct. The distances from observer 2 to the front and back of the train should be length contracted in observer 1's frame. The train is not length contracted in observer 2's frame. The result of lack of simultaneity holds under the replacement you suggested.

Comment: @Aiden Thank you! If you write this as an answer, I will accept it :)